# Changing class variable and print them on kivy screen labels

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

**Python code:**

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen,FadeTransition
from kivy.app import App
import copy

class introscreen(ScreenManager,Screen):
    pass

class screenone(Screen):
    pass

class screentwo(Screen):
    slips = []

    def Flowerscopy(self):
        Flower = ["Rose", "Tulips", "Sunflower", "Marigold"]
        slips = copy.copy(Flower)



class testApp(App):
    SO = screenone()
    ST = screentwo()
    def build(self):
        return introscreen()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    testApp().run()
```

**.kv code**

```
 <introscreen>:
 #: import SlideTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.SlideTransition

 transition: SlideTransition()
 screenone:
 screentwo:

<screenone>:
 name: "One"
 FloatLayout:
     BoxLayout:
         orientation: "vertical"
         size_hint: 0.50,0.50
         pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5,"top":0.75}
         Button:
             text: "Flowers"
             size_hint: 0.5,2.5
             pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5}
             on_release:
                 app.root.transition = SlideTransition(direction = 'left')
                 app.root.current = "Two"
                 app.ST.Flowerscopy()
<screentwo>:
  name: "Two"
  BoxLayout:
     orientation : "horizontal"
     pos_hint : {"center_x": 0.2,"top": 0.2}
     size_hint: 0.80,0.30
     Label:
         id: s1
         text: str(root.slips[0])
```

I am practicing my kivy basics.**I am getting a problem of error getting index out of range error** 
when i try to put a text on a label of the **slips list** in **class screentwo** and i want to change the slips content to **Flower slips** using **Flowerscopy() calling in screen one** and also wants to print on label as the slips are empty they give me error Please help me out i am a beginner now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a modified version of your code that does what I think you want:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen
from kivy.app import App


class introscreen(ScreenManager):
    pass


class screenone(Screen):
    pass


class screentwo(Screen):
    slips = ListProperty(['']*4)

    def Flowerscopy(self):
        Flower = ["Rose", "Tulips", "Sunflower", "Marigold"]
        self.slips = Flower


Builder.load_string('''
#: import SlideTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.SlideTransition

<screenone>:
    name: "One"
    FloatLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1,0,0,1
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        BoxLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 0,1,0,1
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
            orientation: "vertical"
            size_hint: 0.50,0.50
            pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5,"top":0.75}
            Button:
                text: "Flowers"
                size_hint: None, None
                size: self.texture_size
                size_hint: 0.5,2.5
                pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5}
                on_release:
                    app.root.transition = SlideTransition(direction = 'left')
                    app.root.current = "Two"
                    app.ST.Flowerscopy()
<screentwo>:
    name: "Two"
    BoxLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1,0,0,1
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        orientation : "horizontal"
        pos_hint : {"center_x": 0.2,"top": 0.2}
        size_hint: 0.80,0.30
        Label:
            id: s1
            text: root.slips[0]
''')



class testApp(App):
    SO = screenone()
    ST = screentwo()
    def build(self):
        theRoot = introscreen()
        theRoot.add_widget(self.SO)
        theRoot.add_widget(self.ST)
        return theRoot


if __name__ == "__main__":
    testApp().run()
```

I have added your 'kv' file as a `Builder.load_string()` just for my own convenience.

The first change is to make `introscreen` extend only `ScreenManager`. Extending both `ScreenMananger` and `Screen` in the same `Widget` is not a good idea, and will likely lead to problems.

Next, your `slips` needs to be a `ListProperty`. Using a `Property` allows `kv` to  create bindings that will allow your `Label.text` to be automatically updated when the `Property` (`slips`) is modified.

In order to access `app.ST` and `app.SO`, you need the definitions of `SO` and `ST` in your `testApp` to be references to the actual instances of those `Screens` that are used in your display. In your original code, two sets of `Screens` were being created. The ones in your `testApp` code and the ones in your 'kv' file. My changes eliminate the `<introscreen>` rule from the `kv` file, and just builds `introscreen` in the `build()` method.

Also, the `Flowerscopy()` method can simply assign a new `List` to the `slips` `ListProperty`. And since the elements of `slips` are already strings, there is no need of the `str()` call.

The index error is caused because the initial value of your `slips` is an empty list. My code `slips = ListProperty(['']*4)` sets the initial value to a list of empty strings so that the index error is not encountered.

Comment: I used your suggestions in my code But they are giving me warning [WARNING] [Multiple screens named "screenone"] [<Screen name='screenone'>, <Screen name='screenone'>]
[WARNING] [Multiple screens named "screentwo"] [<Screen name='screentwo'>, <Screen name='screentwo'>]

Comment: The code I posted does not give that error. If you have another question, you should post another question with your current code.